# react-hook-form integrate with server-side validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, yup

I have a Form with various fields within nested components (each of them having various fields). I am using a react-hook-forms based library

```
import {Form} from '@mycustomfw/forms'; //based on react-hook-form (uncontrolled)

<Form 
    style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}
    defaultValues={defaultValues}
    mode={"onChange"}
    reValidateMode={"onBlur"}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    ref={formRef}>
    <NestedComponentsWithInputFields />
</Form>                             

setValidationSchema(createValidationSchema(response));
```

My ValidationSchema is as below. It kind of iterates over the fields and sets up the validations

```
export const createValidationSchema = (response) => {
    response.fields.forEach(field => {  
        let validator;  
        validator = Yup.string();

        if (field.mandatory) {
            validator = validator.required(`${field.fieldLabel} is required`);
        }   
        if (field.hasOwnProperty('regex')) {
            validator = validator.matches(
                new RegExp(field.regex),
                "Regex error"
            );
        }

        schema[field.id] = validator;                
    });
    return Yup.object(schema);
}
```

With this setup, the basic validations work fine.
But my question is for some fields, I want to also perform server-side validations and display error messages below the field for them.

Is it possible to integrate the Yup schema with server-side validations ?
Also, can the trigger point for this validation be different from the overall page Submit? i.e. I have a button next to a "user-id" field saying "Check user id available" and want to make an API call and accordingly validate and display error message below this field based on the API response.

Comment: May this SO q/a be to inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839218/how-to-do-i-do-server-side-validation-using-formik-and-yup

Comment: @RoarS. : yes, it does give an idea about the custom validation itself...but what is still not clear from this link is how the API validation/function can be triggered on say some other link/button click, instead of the Submit button on which all validations get triggered by default